# Git Joomla - Sync Database Updates

Tags: database, git, joomla, continuous-integration

I have a deployment system where updates are performed locally and pushed up to production using Git and CI. Now I do this ok with Wordpress and Drupal as they both have the option of upgrading the database on the production server. However I can not find how to do this on Joomla. I do not want to copy the database from my local to production. It needs to be sync down only as users are making changes as I am doing the upgrade.

Comment: Go to Extensions, Extension Manager, Database.  If it says your database is not up to date click Fix. Oh  I think I misunderstood the questions, you mean you want to push the changes?

Comment: Thanks, I actually just found it about 20 minutes ago. :)